# How to make a reusable component which renders data based on object structure?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make a reusable InfoBlock component. This component renders a list of items. Each item has a label, icon and value. The problem that I don't know how to map available `INFO_BLOCK_ITEMS` to data object and render only items which present in data object.

Full list of all available labels and icons looks like this:

```
const INFO_BLOCK_ITEMS = {
  author: {
    label: "Author",
    icon: AccountTreeIcon
  },
  date: {
    label: "Created",
    icon: FaceRetouchingNaturalIcon
  },
  rawMedias: {
    label: "RAW Medias",
    icon: InsertDriveFileOutlinedIcon
  },
  face: {
    label: "Faces",
    icon: ScheduleOutlinedIcon,
    faceAction: true,
  },
  s3Source: {
    label: "S3 Source",
    icon: AcUnitIcon
  }
};
```

Data object which I pass to `InfoBlock` component along with dataType (for another page, the data structure will be different but it will contain the keys from `INFO_BLOCK_ITEMS`:

```
const DATASET = {
  author: "extrauser@site.com",
  date: 1669208819,
  rawMedias: "Video name 1, Video name 2, Video name 3",
  face: ""
};

<InfoBlock data={DATASET} type={"dataset"} />
```

The result should be a list like this for every key in data object:

```
  <Stack>
    <AccountTreeIcon />
    <Stack>
      <Typography>Author</Typography>
      <Typography>extrauser@site.com</Typography>
    </Stack>
  </Stack>
```

Here's a **Codesandbox** with hardcoded list: https://codesandbox.io/s/info-block-forked-0bwrze?file=/src/InfoBlock.tsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't need to pass type to InfoBlock component.
2. data in Rawmedia type should be number.
3. Use icons as React component.

Hope it helps.

Types:

```js
export type Dataset = {
  author: string;
  date: number;
  rawMedias: string;
  face: string;
};

export type RawMedia = {
  s3Source: string;
  author: string;
  date: number;
  face: string;
};
```

InfoBlock Component:

```js
const INFO_BLOCK_ITEMS = {
  author: {
    label: "Author",
    icon: <AccountTreeIcon />
  },
  date: {
    label: "Created",
    icon: <FaceRetouchingNaturalIcon />
  },
  rawMedias: {
    label: "RAW Medias",
    icon: <InsertDriveFileOutlinedIcon />
  },
  face: {
    label: "Faces",
    icon: <ScheduleOutlinedIcon />,
    action: () => console.log("If no data then button renders")
  },
  s3Source: {
    label: "S3 Source",
    icon: <AcUnitIcon />
  }
};

interface IInfoBlockProps {
  data: Dataset | RawMedia;
}

function InfoBlock({ data }: IInfoBlockProps) {
  return(
    <Stack gap={"20px"}>
      {
        Object.keys(data).map((key, _index) => {
          const infoBlockItem = INFO_BLOCK_ITEMS[key];
          return (
            <Stack key={_index} direction={"row"} gap={"10px"}>
              {infoBlockItem.icon}
              <Stack direction={"row"} gap={"20px"}>
                <Typography>{infoBlockItem.label}</Typography>
                <Typography>{data[key]}</Typography>
              </Stack>
            </Stack>
          );
        })
      }
    </Stack>
  )
}
```

App Component:

```js
const DATASET = {
  author: "extrauser@example.com",
  date: 1669208819.837662,
  rawMedias: "Video name 1, Video name 2, Video name 3",
  face: ""
};

const RAW_MEDIA = {
  s3Source: "https://example.com",
  author: "extrauser@example.com",
  date: 1669208819.837662,
  face: "Some face"
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <InfoBlock data={DATASET} />
      <InfoBlock data={RAW_MEDIA} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. May I ask one more question please? I added UPD to initial post. Also I added "action prop" in INFO_BLOCK_ITEMS for face key.

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry I don't understand what you mean. It it a question ?